# how to view TFS API report data in share point project portal

Tags: reporting-services, tfs-reports, tfs-analysis

I am using TFS APIs through c# application to create some customised TFS reports and charts. I am connecting to data source and creating data set programatically.
I want to know is there any way to upload these report on share point server or project portal page?

OR what type of report should I create using TFS APIs so it can be uploaded on share point poject portal.